# Google Cloud Pub/Sub, publishing with a HTTP PUSH request

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to use google clouds pub/sub feature to store incoming data from an IOT device. I have an event call back which should be sending a JSON string to the pub/sub topic, from the IOT device's back-end. The callback looks like this (where {project},{topic} and {YOUR_API_KEY} are filled in as required:

```
POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project}/topics/{topic}:publish?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{"messages":[{"data":"test"}]}
```

I am invariably getting error 403 with this set up. I have tried various slight variations on this and found other errors. I am very new to this topic, is there an obvious mistake I am making?

Answer (score 0):

API Keys are not sufficient for authenticating to the Google Cloud Pub/Sub API. Only a subset of GCP services allow access using only an API key, as detailed in the [Using API Keys documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys). You will need to use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) to authenticate for using Cloud Pub/Sub. You might also want to consider [Google Cloud IoT](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/iot/), which sends telemetry into Cloud Pub/Sub.

Comment: This documentation explicitly gives examples that use API keys to change policy on pubsub topics: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control

Comment: The documentation specifically states that API keys are not supported: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/authentication#more-information. Perhaps these examples need to be updated.